# disable send diagnostics data to application insights on publish settings

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've created a web role on vs2013 and recently upgraded it to vs2015.

When publishing the role to Azure, the `send diagnostics data to application insights` is turned on.

[image]

Since I don't want to use the application insights each time, when I need to publish my role I need to uncheck the checkbox.

Is there a way to permanently uncheck this option?

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid getting the "Diagnostics" tab in the publish dialog by following these steps:

- Open the *Properties* page for one of the roles in your project
- Under *Diagnostics*, check the *"Send diagnostics data to Application Insights"* checkbox
- Select to manually specify the Application Insights instrumentation key
- Enter some value in the textbox (doesn't matter what value) and click *OK*
- After the dialog closes, the value you have entered will appear in a textbox under the checkbox mentioned in the previous step
- Delete that value and click save

After doing this, you should no longer see the option to send diagnostics data to Application Insights during the publish process. Also, because a valid instrumentation key wan't provided, the extention that sends the diagnostics data to Application Insights will not be started.

Comment: I don't see any diagnostics tab when right clicking a role project in VS2015

Comment: What version of Azure SDK do you have installed?

Comment: Azure SDK 2.9. I think this is the latest

Comment: And just to make sure, are you right-clicking the Cloud Service node (and not the role project node)?
This option is available on the publish wizard of the Cloud Service node

Comment: VS 2015 there is no checkbox 'Send diagnostics data to Application Insights' in the Properties pages that I can find.